# Ubuntu Wont Write a Win7 ISO to a USB

Tags: installation, windows-7

I'm trying to find a program or terminal code that can write a 3.1 GB Windows 7 Installer File to a 32 GB USB3+ flash stick.

I have tried the Startup Disk Creator but it won't select the Windows installer File. Any suggestions that I could use? (I'm new to Ubuntu)

Comment: When you say "it won't select the Windows installer File" Can you explain a bit more in depth of how it is acting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) under windows or wine?

Answer (score 0):

[This guide may help](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) It uses unetbootin to create the usb.